# Chrome developer tools console doesn't show me the filename

Tags: reactjs, laravel, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on Laravel-React project.
Chrome developer tools console doesn't show me the filename where the error or the log come from.
It shows me something like app.js:12345 , is it possible to know from which file come from or change something in the webpack config or package json to have it automatically?

[image: Chrome developer tools]

Thanks

Comment: your all file is comiled in app.js that's why u r not getting exact file name

Comment: try changing in the webpack as devtool: 'source-map'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it.
I added .sourceMaps(true, "source-map") in webpack.mix.js

Thanks